# Having some trouble with Spark and Lambda functions

Tags: python, pyspark, lambda

I am having some trouble with understanding lambda functions

```
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()

topWords = [('the', 8877), ('to', 5541), ('a', 5485)....]
```

list of tuples with word and counts (20,000 words)

```
twentyK = sc.parallelize(range(20000))
twentyK = [0, 1, 2, .....]
```

I want to map the parallelized range (0,1,2,…,) into a set of tuples ("mostcommonword", 0), ("nextmostcommon", 1), ....

**so like ("the", 0), ("to", 1), ("a", 2) ..... for all 20,000 words**

I want to use a lambda function

```
dictionary = twentyK.map ( ________lambda function______)
```

I tried this:

```
dictionary = twentyK.map (lambda x: topWords[x], twentyK)

[('the', 8877),
 ('to', 5541),
 ('a', 5485),
 ('and', 4887),
 ('of', 4559),
 ('i', 3817),
 ('is', 3518),
 ('in', 3259),
 ('for', 3226),
 ('it', 2731)]
```

but it doesn't map the words to rankings and I am not sure why

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

i guess

```
# maybe its already sorted so you can skip this step    
sorted_20k = sorted(twentyk,lambda x:x[1])



# now just match index to item like so... 
items = [(item[0],i) for i,item in enumerate(sorted_20k)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this chunk of code will be helping you in this regard

```py
topWords = [('the', 8877), ('to', 5541), ('a', 5485)....]
newRange = SparkContext.parallelize(range(20000))
dictionary = newRange.map(lambda x: (topWords[x][0] ,x))
```

This will solve the problem
and you will get values like this

````py
[('the', 1),
 ('to', 2),
 ('a', 3), ... ]```
````